# Passing access token to google api (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, token

I'm trying to authenticate a google api request by passing the access_token, but I'm receiving an invalid credentials error from google. I know that the access token is correct, but I think I'm passing it incorrectly. What is the correct way to pass the access token?

Here's my code, closely based off of [Google's quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs#step_2_install_the_client_library)

```
  listEvents: function(req, res) {
    var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
    calendar.events.list({
      access_token: req.user.accessToken,
      calendarId: 'primary',
      timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
      maxResults: 10,
      singleEvents: true,
      orderBy: 'startTime'
    }, function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        return;
      }
      var events = response.items;
      if (events.length == 0) {
        console.log('No upcoming events found.');
      } else {
        console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          var event = events[i];
          var start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
          console.log('%s - %s', start, event.summary);
        }
      }
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I realized that my accessToken had simply expired. The code above does in fact show the correct way to pass the access token. However, if this access token has expired, you have to get a new one using the refresh token.